# \vbox to height placement depending on its contents

Tags: boxes

I have created a custom titlepage for a template I'm working on at the moment and encountered some strange behavior of `\vbox`. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside
    ,fontsize=11pt
    ,paper=a4
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm,top=9mm,bottom=22.6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\my@title}{Entwicklung}% this works
\newcommand{\my@title}{Dies ist ein sehr intelligenter Titel, der ein wenig länger ist als die meisten. Das muss er aber auch sein, um schön zu sein.}% this doesn't
\newcommand{\my@author}{Eins Student\\\vfill Zwei Student\\\vfill Drei Student}
\newcommand{\my@shortauthor}{E. Student, Z. Student, D. Student}
\newcommand{\my@thesis}{Teamprojekt}
\newcommand{\my@examinor}{Prof. Dr. Dings Bumsenskirchen}
\newcommand{\my@shortexaminor}{D. Bumsenskirchen}
\newcommand{\my@advisor}{Dipl.-Depp Hans Bumsenskirchen}
\newcommand{\my@shortadvisor}{H. Bumsenskirchen}
\newcommand{\my@number}{XX-00-AA-0}

\newcommand{\multfill}[1]{%
    \bgroup%
    \newcount\@multfillmax%
    \newcount\@multfillcur%
    \@multfillmax=#1%
    \@multfillcur=0%
    \loop\ifnum\@multfillmax>\@multfillcur%
        \advance\@multfillcur by 1%
        \vfill%
    \repeat%
    \egroup%
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newgeometry{left=25mm,right=25mm,top=9mm,bottom=22.6mm}%
    \vbox to 0.96\textheight{%
        \setstretch{1}\noindent%
        \includegraphics[height=10.85mm]{example-image-a}%
        \hfill\includegraphics[height=11.9mm]{example-image-b}%
        \multfill{9}%
        \begin{center}%
        {%
            \setstretch{1.4}\bfseries\huge\my@title\\%
            \multfill{2}%
            \setstretch{1}\large von\\%
            \multfill{2}%
            \my@author\\%}}}
        }%
        \multfill{5}%
        {\setstretch{1.15}\large\textbf{\my@thesis}}%
        \multfill{5}%
        {\setstretch{1.15}\large Ausgegeben von\\\textbf{\my@examinor},\\%
            mitbetreut von\\\textbf{\my@advisor}\\%
        }
        \multfill{5}%
        {\setstretch{1.15}\large Lehrstuhl für eine Wissenschaft\\%
            Fakultät für Wissenschaft, Universität\\%
        }%
        \multfill{2}%
        \textbf{\@date}\\%
        \end{center}%
        \multfill{5}%
        \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\setstretch{1.07}\small Zitierhinweis:\\
            \my@shortauthor, \my@shortadvisor, \my@shortexaminor:%
            \\\my@title,\\LS1-Bericht Nr. \my@number; Stadt (\the\year)%
        }
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

With this the titlepage ends up on the second page of the pdf. If I replace `\newcommand{\my@title}{...}` with `\newcommand{\my@title}{Entwicklung}` the titlepage ends up on the first page.

My question is therefore: Why does a `\vbox` which is set to a total height (in this case `0.96\textheight`) end up on different pages depending on its contents?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Surely, the descender on `g` does not extend to `.04\textheight`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I misread the question

Comment: @Skillmon sorry I commented before I ran the question I thought you meant `...`  it's just teh longer title is longer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the final item in your box is

```
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\setstretch{1.07}\small Zitierhinweis:\\
            \my@shortauthor, \my@shortadvisor, \my@shortexaminor:%
            \\\my@title,\\LS1-Bericht Nr. \my@number; Stadt (\the\year)%
```

which as you have not used `[b]` is a vertically centred parbox so half of its total height contributes to the *depth* of the outer box this depth is increased when you have a two-line title.

```
 \parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{\setstretch{1.07}\small Zitierhinweis:\\
            \my@shortauthor, \my@shortadvisor, \my@shortexaminor:%
            \\\my@title,\\LS1-Bericht Nr. \my@number; Stadt (\the\year)%
        }%
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I hate it when the solution is that simple :) It always bothers me that I should have spotted this on my own.